# How to debug obfuscated Android code?

Tags: android

After I updated my Android app yesterday, I'm getting this strange error only from some Samsung Galaxy Note II. I have some Note II devices and I couldn't replicate the issue on my own.

(Line 97 is the line that starts with the  tag)

I am sure my class is extending the v4.fragment and FragmentActivity because it works on every devices I have tested it on. But I still get these crash reports and I have no idea how to go about fixing the issues.

Any ideas?

`Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zyz.mobile/com.zyz.mobile.jade.JadeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
at com.zyz.mobile.jade.JadeActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.zyz.mobile.jade.BookshelfFragment.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.p.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.p.b(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.p.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.h.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
... 21 more`

The XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        >

    <com.zyz.mobile.widget.MyButton
            android:id="@+id/bookshelf_help"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/jade_button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/help"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            />

    <com.zyz.mobile.widget.MyButton
            android:id="@+id/bookshelf_option"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/jade_button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/option"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            />

    <com.zyz.mobile.widget.MyButton
            android:id="@+id/bookshelf_open"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/jade_button"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/open_book"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            />

</LinearLayout>
<com.zyz.mobile.widget.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/history_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/history_title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        />

<fragment
        class="com.zyz.mobile.jade.BookshelfFragment"
        android:id="@+id/bookshelf_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the stack trace you can see the issue is caused by a null pointer exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.zyz.mobile.jade.BookshelfFragment.a(Unknown Source)

Is this a library or something you wrote?  If you get the source, you could put a breakpoint there and see exactly what the problem is.

Edit: Due to the method named 'a' I am assuming this is a stack trace reported from Google Play on a build that has ProGuard.  [Please read about debugging obfuscated code traces here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding).

Comment: That's my own Fragment. And I have no idea what is the 'a' variable that it is referencing to. I'll try to debug in that direction. Thanks.

Comment: Is the stack trace from a release build that has ProGuard?  It's likely that is your problem.

Comment: I see. Then I think it's better if I don't run ProGuard then, since it's an open source application. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's unlikely that you'll need ProGuard for an open source application.  You probably won't know for a while, but if this has helped, please accept the answer.

Comment: Omg! Thanks for the link to how to debug obfuscated code. I was able to reproduce this problem on my phone! now I can debug it!